# Genymotion on Arch Linux: Virtual Device Instantly Disappears When Booting

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox, genymotion, archlinux

I am trying to start an Android Emulator using Genymotion and Virtual Machine on Arch Linux OS.

VirtualBox was installed from community and Genymotion from AUR. When I start the custom virtual device I create, it instantly shuts down on booting state before the Android logo arrives. It does not show up an error message.

I have already reinstalled everything to try from the beginning again and again.

When I do: `sudo vboxreload` from `/usr/lib/virtualbox`

It says: `Loading modules: vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci vboxdrv`

- `virtualbox-host-dkms` is not installed.
- `virtualbox-host-modules-arch` was installed. (5.2.14-1)
- `Use Host GPU` option from Virtual Device settings was unchecked.

Error message on VirtualBox screen:

[image: vm]

My Genymotion Log from `genymotion-player.log` at `Genymotion/deployed/custom-phone`

```
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] "Cannot init install path settings (status=1) /opt/genymotion/genymotion.ini"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Host date and time: "11 Jul 2018 15:32:53 +0300"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [critical] File:  "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed//Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/.flag"  Already exists, player may have crashed before.
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] "Local socket created at path: /tmp/670fca602215dfbee6ca4fcbb304ba44"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] Player version: "2.12.1"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb] adb found at "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Checking device compatibility
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Received message "PING"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Trying to log in as "Dentrax"
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Virtual Machine status: on
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Trying to reconnect...
2018-07-11T15:32:53+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Boot successful
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Error: "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] error with device connection "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] "publisher" is connected, context 0x7f893c004d80
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] "subscriber" is connected, context 0x7f899c015e80
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Player running. Try to show window...
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [TemplateUuid] Device "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280" has template uuid property "f028a901-70e3-4d31-8aca-3993d2dbcde3"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=768 h=1280
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] FrameBuffer::initialize
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] call eglInitialize
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] egl: 1 4
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl context
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl pbuffer context
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] context creation successful
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] attempting to make context current
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] context-current successful
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] host system has enough extensions
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] There are sufficient EGLconfigs available
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] basic EGL initialization successful
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [emugl.debug] OpenGL renderer initialized successfully
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] OpenGL connected to: "192.168.56.102" : 25000
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Aapt] aapt found at "/home/dentrax/android/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt"
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:54+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][logcat] "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/logcat-J13067.txt" : "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] "User Dentrax (furkan.turkal@hotmail.com) logged on Hub"
2018-07-11T15:32:55+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:32:56+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:32:56+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:32:56+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-07-11T15:32:56+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13067] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 10 - "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN."
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [warning] "Cannot init install path settings (status=1) /opt/genymotion/genymotion.ini"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Host date and time: "11 Jul 2018 15:33:30 +0300"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [critical] File:  "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed//Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/.flag"  Already exists, player may have crashed before.
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] "Local socket created at path: /tmp/670fca602215dfbee6ca4fcbb304ba44"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [warning] Player version: "2.12.1"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [Adb] adb found at "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Checking device compatibility
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Received message "PING"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Trying to log in as "Dentrax"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Virtual Machine status: on
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Trying to reconnect...
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Boot successful
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [warning] QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Error: "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [warning] error with device connection "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] "subscriber" is connected, context 0x7f2278015e80
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] "publisher" is connected, context 0x7f2214004d80
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Player running. Try to show window...
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [TemplateUuid] Device "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280" has template uuid property "f028a901-70e3-4d31-8aca-3993d2dbcde3"
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=768 h=1280
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] FrameBuffer::initialize
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] call eglInitialize
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] egl: 1 4
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl context
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl pbuffer context
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] context creation successful
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] attempting to make context current
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] context-current successful
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] host system has enough extensions
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] There are sufficient EGLconfigs available
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] basic EGL initialization successful
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [emugl.debug] OpenGL renderer initialized successfully
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] OpenGL connected to: "192.168.56.102" : 25000
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:30+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:33:31+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [Aapt] aapt found at "/home/dentrax/android/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt"
2018-07-11T15:33:31+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:33:31+03:00 [Genymotion Player:13711] [debug] [Adb][logcat] "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/logcat-J13711.txt" : "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] "Cannot init install path settings (status=1) /opt/genymotion/genymotion.ini"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Host date and time: "11 Jul 2018 15:34:48 +0300"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [critical] File:  "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed//Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/.flag"  Already exists, player may have crashed before.
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] "Local socket created at path: /tmp/670fca602215dfbee6ca4fcbb304ba44"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] Player version: "2.12.1"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb] adb found at "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Received message "PING"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Checking device compatibility
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Trying to log in as "Dentrax"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Virtual Machine status: on
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Trying to reconnect...
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Boot successful
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:48+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Error: "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] error with device connection "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] "subscriber" is connected, context 0x7f3f50008160
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] "publisher" is connected, context 0x7f3eec004d80
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Player running. Try to show window...
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [TemplateUuid] Device "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280" has template uuid property "f028a901-70e3-4d31-8aca-3993d2dbcde3"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=768 h=1280
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] FrameBuffer::initialize
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] call eglInitialize
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] egl: 1 4
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl context
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl pbuffer context
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] context creation successful
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] attempting to make context current
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] context-current successful
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] host system has enough extensions
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] There are sufficient EGLconfigs available
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] basic EGL initialization successful
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [emugl.debug] OpenGL renderer initialized successfully
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] OpenGL connected to: "192.168.56.102" : 25000
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Aapt] aapt found at "/home/dentrax/android/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][logcat] "/home/dentrax/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280/logcat-J14572.txt" : "192.168.56.102"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] "User Dentrax (furkan.turkal@hotmail.com) logged on Hub"
2018-07-11T15:34:49+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" ) 
2018-07-11T15:34:50+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [warning] Activation failed. Error: 10 - "HTTP code 403: Activation failed: license have never been registered Error downloading https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/ - server replied: FORBIDDEN."
2018-07-11T15:34:50+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:50+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:50+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-07-11T15:34:51+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:51+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/home/dentrax/android/platform-tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-07-11T15:34:51+03:00 [Genymotion Player:14572] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
```